# Tomcat/Java debug information

Tags: java, tomcat, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to trace an error down in an existing system. So the problem is that Tomcat doesn't give me the line in which the error occurred, but just a general NULL-pointer exception. The current system uses servlets that get a reference to a bean. This bean class does all the data handling and whenever an error occurs within such a bean, I won't be able to find the error unless I debug the code manually, which is not possible for some errors that just happen once in a while. Are there any flags which I can enable to get more information? Or do I have to re-design the system to get debug information?
I'm working with Tomcat version 7.0.12. 
Thanks!

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.search_jsp._jspService(search_jsp.java:151)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at ...
```

Edit: Just found out that the exception handling in the servlet tried to access a property of a null object, which caused the original error to be disguised with that null pointer exception.

Comment: Can you give me your tomcat version?

Comment: Looks like it's giving you the line to me; look at the Java file generated from the JSP. If your bean doesn't do any useful logging, and you haven't tested it outside the app, your options are limited. Note you can also log inside JSPs, but there's rarely a need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to $TOMCAT_HOME/work/catalina/localhost/${YOUR_APP_NAME}/org/apache/jsp/..

and find the file search_jsp.java. So you'll be able to find the line where the error happened.

Comment: Hey, the problem is, that the errors happens whithin the compiled bean class not in the servlet itself, so expanded jsp file doesn't help me.

Comment: Stacktrace says: org.apache.jsp.search_jsp._jspService(search_jsp.java:151)

What the code is in the line? Do you have any additional info?

Comment: Yeah, it calls a method of the bean: bean.search(...)

Comment: Are you sure the bean is not null? Otherwise the stack trace would point to some code line in the bean source. Can you print the bean on the page and check if it exists (like [${bean}])

Comment: Oh... thank you so much! It actually tried to get a property from an object which was null in a catch{} block, which caused the original error to be masked by the null pointer exception...